# DiIemma in choosing which way to create this page

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am new to swift, I have a dilemma to create the page shown in the screenshot. I had an initial thought to create this whole page with a `UICollectionView` with a `UITableView` inside one of the cells. But the method seems quite difficult, and I am confused on how to implement a sliding method to switch between the Edit Profile and Photos page. Anyone here can enlighten me ? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Ru asking about that Brown Line sliding effect ??

Comment: @McDonal_11 I mean i don't know how to do it if the whole page is a UItableview or UIcollectionview.

Comment: What I am asking, are you asking about how that brown line move to photos , when I click photos ??

Comment: @McDonal_11 Oh I see, I think this part I know how to do

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use UITableViewController and can take table view inside a cell.  for the detail expand and fold.

Comment: then inside the cell, how to slide to switch the Photos part which is a UIcollectionview?

Comment: You can have two separate views for Profile and photos. One ViewController, two views. you can do this way. @karenr

Comment: you can take collection view inside the tableview  cell.

Answer (score 0):

I am implementing such screens as following:
1) Separate view for header(avatar, name, age, premium badge). You put this view into headerView property of UITableView.
2) You implement separator(Edit Prof|Photos) as subview of header.
3) Basic Information looks like SectionHeaderView on first section of UITableVIew
4) After that you are left with simple table view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `containerView` and manage the view as a `childViewController`.

```
// The main viewController
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    public lazy var vc1: UITableViewController = {
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableViewController") as? UITableViewController else { fatalError() }
        return vc
    }()

    public lazy var vc2: UICollectionViewController = {
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewController") as? UICollectionViewController else { fatalError() }
        return vc
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        addVC(vc1)
    }

    // outlet is linked to a UISegmentedControl and trigged when the value is changed
    @IBAction func didSelectSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        let (vcToAdd, vcToRemove) = sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? (vc1, vc2) : (vc2, vc1)
        removeVC(vcToRemove)
        addVC(vcToAdd)
    }

    func addVC(_ vc: UIViewController) {
        addChildViewController(vc)
        containerView.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vc.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        // additional setup
    }

    func removeVC(_ vc: UIViewController) {
        vc.view.removeFromSuperview()
        vc.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tvCell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "tvCell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = indexPath.row.description
        return cell
    }

}

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cvCell", for: indexPath) as? CVCell else { fatalError() }
        cell.nameLabel.text = indexPath.row.description
        return cell
    }
}

class CVCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
}
```

**UITableViewController**
[image: UITableViewController]

**UICollectionViewController**
[image: UICollectionViewController]